# Pycharm can't import packages and displayed SSL error in my vmware machine windows 7

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

I enabled KeyExchangeAlgorithms disabled firewall

```
from ctypes import *
from my_debugger_defines import *
import sys
import time
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
class debugger():
 def __init__(self):
 self.h_process = None
 self.pid = None
 self.debugger_active = False

 def load(self,path_to_exe):
 ...
 print "[*] We have successfully launched the process!"
 print "[*] The Process ID I have is: %d" %
process_information.dwProcessId

 # Obtain a valid handle to the newly created process
 # and store it for future access
 self.h_process = self.open_process(process_information.dwProcessId)
 ...
 def open_process(self,pid):
 h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,pid,False)
 return h_process
 def attach(self,pid):
 self.h_process = self.open_process(pid)
 # We attempt to attach to the process
 # if this fails we exit the call
 if kernel32.DebugActiveProcess(pid):
 self.debugger_active = True
 self.pid = int(pid)
 else:
 print "[*] Unable to attach to the process."
 def detach(self):
if kernel32.DebugActiveProcessStop(self.pid):
 print "[*] Finished debugging. Exiting..."
 return True`enter code here`
 else:
 print "There was an error"
 return False
```

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: provide a better screenshot or rewrite the SSL error

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: problems importing packages because of SSL